# Why is this working differently in Firefox, Chrome and IE?

Tags: css, html-table, centering, onmouseover

I just wanted to ask the following :

1. Why does table behave in a strange way in different browsers? Is this behavior same with other tags? Even my data, though being repeatedly centered doesn't displays the way it should.Is something wrong with the way I used 'test-align'? (I have not found out yet any differences with other tags)
2. When I try to put an 'id' attribute in `<td element>` why does it appears to behave like a block element?
3. How can I change the onMOuseOut so that it does not close until my mouse is out from the option that are displayed?

```css
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}

#header {
height:150px;
background-color:green;
margin:10px;
}

#navbar {
height:60px;
background-color:teal;
text-align:center;
margin:10px;
padding:0px;
}


#hlink1{
background-color:lime;
text-align:center;
height:40px;
padding:3px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}

#hlink2{
background-color:lime;
text-align:center;
height:40px;
padding:3px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}

#hlink3{
background-color:lime;
text-align:center;
height:40px;
padding:3px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}

#hlink1:hover{
background-color:aqua;
text-align:center;
}

#hlink2:hover{
background-color:aqua;
text-align:center;
}

#hlink3:hover{
background-color:aqua;
text-align:center;
}


table {
width:100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
text-align:center;
}

#data3 {
background-color:lime;
padding:5px;
height:0px;
display:none;
}

#data2 {
background-color:lime;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
height:0px;
display:none;
}

#data1 {
background-color:lime;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
height:0px;
display:none;
}

.inn:hover{
background-color:aqua;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Experiment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="navbar">
<table>
 <th onMouseOver="document.getElementById('data1').style.display='inline';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('data1').style.display='none';">
 <div id="hlink1">Heading_Link1</div>
 </th>
 <th onMouseOver="document.getElementById('data2').style.display='inline';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('data2').style.display='none';">
 <div id="hlink2">Heading_Link2</div>
 </th>
 <th onMouseOver="document.getElementById('data3').style.display='inline';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('data3').style.display='none';">
 <div id="hlink3">Heading_link3</div>
 </th>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="1">
  <table  id="data1">
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
  </table>
  </td>
 
  <td>
  <table  id="data2">
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
  </table>
  </td>

 
  <td>
  <table  id="data3">
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
  </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain your point 2? Which element starts behaving like a block element?

Comment: td element. In firefox. it has a width of 28 px while in chrom it has the width of that of the table element and same with IE

Comment: Hm, interesting. No idea, sorry. By the way, I did edit my answer just now to solve point 3; hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to change the `display` value of a table without also changing the display values of the structure inside it. While not technically an error, this amounts to putting a `tr` inside a `span`; which the browsers apparently handle differently.
Now if you change the mouseover events to read

```
document.getElementById('data1').style.display='table';
```

they will act the same in all browsers.

As for point 3, that may require a little change in structure. Currently, the data tables are in different rows than the hover rows, so they don't influence each other. If you put those data tables directly inside the header cells, it's much easier to do the hovering; you won't even need the JavaScript events.

```html
<th>
  <div id="hlink1">Heading_Link1</div>
  <table  id="data1">
    <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
  </table>
</th>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#navbar th:hover table {
  display:table
}
```

No need to spell out all the onmouseover actions in each of the header cells!

```css
body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px
}

#header {
  height:150px;
  background-color:green;
  margin:10px;
}

#navbar {
  height:60px;
  background-color:teal;
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px;
  padding:0px;
}


#hlink1, #hlink2, #hlink3 {
  background-color:lime;
  text-align:center;
  height:40px;
  padding:3px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

#hlink1:hover, #hlink2:hover, #hlink3:hover{
  background-color:aqua;
}

table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:center;
}

#data1, #data2, #data3 {
  background-color:lime;
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
}

.inn:hover{
  background-color:aqua;
}

#navbar th {
  vertical-align:top;
}

#navbar th:hover table {
  display:table
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
      <table>
        <th>
          <div id="hlink1">Heading_Link1</div>
          <table  id="data1">
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
          </table>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div id="hlink2">Heading_Link2</div>
          <table  id="data2">
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
          </table>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div id="hlink3">Heading_link3</div>
          <table  id="data3">
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="inn">data</td></tr>
          </table>
        </th>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you briefly say what actually happened when you changed the display value to table from inline? I tried using block value i didn't get the result(The result i got was a <td> element of height 2px and the data outside it).And how did centering change when you changed the display value??

Comment: Like I said, this is similar to not using a `<table>` element, but using a `span` that you put the `tr` elements in. Browsers are supposed to accommodate situations like that, but apparently they don't do it in the same way!